# Terraform deployment for 'Workspace based Application Insight' on Azure

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, terraform-provider-azure

I have been trying to figure out a way to prepare a terraform template for my app service/az function where I can connect it to application Insight while creating them through Terraform. Well the it worked, BUT the application Insight shows

> Migrate this resource to Workspace-based Application Insights to gain support for all of the capabilities of Log Analytics, including Customer-Managed Keys and Commitment Tiers. Click here to learn more and migrate in a few clicks.

How do I acheive it from terraform? As from the documentation page of terraform there is no mention of such setup. Appreciate you help on this.
Here is the terraform code for az-function

```
    resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "t_funcapp" {
  name                = "t-function-app"
  location            = local.resource_location
  resource_group_name = local.resource_group_name
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.t_app_service_plan.id

  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.t_funcstorage.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.t_funcstorage.primary_access_key

  site_config {
    application_stack {
      java_version = "11"
    }
    remote_debugging_enabled = false
    ftps_state = "AllAllowed"
  }
  app_settings = {
    APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY = "${azurerm_application_insights.t_appinsights.instrumentation_key}"
  }
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_resource_group.t_rg,
    azurerm_service_plan.t_app_service_plan,
    azurerm_storage_account.t_funcstorage,
    azurerm_application_insights.t_appinsights
  ]
}
```

Here is the terraform code for app insight

```
resource "azurerm_application_insights" "t_appinsights" {
  name                = "t-appinsights"
  location            = local.resource_location
  resource_group_name = local.resource_group_name
  application_type    = "web"
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.t_workspace
  ]
}

output "instrumentation_key" {
  value = azurerm_application_insights.t_appinsights.instrumentation_key
}

output "app_id" {
  value = azurerm_application_insights.t_appinsights.app_id
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question and add your terraform code. Remember to follow the recommendations about [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must create a Log Analytics Workspace and add it to your Application Insights.

For example

```
resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "example" {
  name                = "workspace-test"
  location            = local.resource_location
  resource_group_name = local.resource_group_name
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
  retention_in_days   = 30
}

resource "azurerm_application_insights" "t_appinsights" {
  name                = "t-appinsights"
  location            = local.resource_location
  resource_group_name = local.resource_group_name
  workspace_id        = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.example.id
  application_type    = "web"
}

output "instrumentation_key" {
  value = azurerm_application_insights.t_appinsights.instrumentation_key
}

output "app_id" {
  value = azurerm_application_insights.t_appinsights.app_id
}
```

Hope this helps!